# Space in WordPress Attribute Causing Problems

Tags: plugins, shortcode

I'm trying to write my first caption plugin and having some difficulties.

I'm setting up a shortcode like so:

```
function Shortcode_Caption( $atts, $content=null ){

   // DEFAULT ARGUMENTS ARRAY       
   $args=shortcode_atts( array(
    'caption' => 'Caption',
    'link' => 'http://www.link.com'
   ), $atts);

   // ENCLOSED SHORTCODES
   if($content){
      return '<div class="Container-Caption" 
        alt="'. $args['caption'] .'" 
        rel="'. $args['link'] .'">
          '.$content.'</div>';
   };
};  

add_shortcode( 'Caption', 'Shortcode_Caption' );
```

Some JS picks it up from there. So then when the shortcode is used:

```
[Caption caption="This is the Text" link="http://www.go_here.com"]some content[/Caption]
```

The above doesn't work, because of the spaces in the "caption" attribute. However, removing the spaces works 100%:

```
[Caption caption="Text" link="http://www.go_here.com"]some content[/Caption]
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong with this?
Thanks!

Comment: Your code is outputting strangely formatted markup but the spaces don't seem to matter. What doesn't work? The Javascript?

Comment: Did you end up finding an answer to this, agreed the HTML markup isn't great but i'm having the same issue of spaces in attributes causing the "shortcode_atts" function to use the default values

Comment: No, no resolution - sorry

Comment: I was having the same issue and abandoned shortcode_parse_atts() to use a regex solution. I found the solution on this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22592608/key-value-pairs-parsing-with-optional-quotes

Answer (score 0):

The way your code is written, you are breaking your `div` tag over several lines-- literally like this, if you look at the generated source:

```
<div class="Container-Caption" 
        alt="Oh I have been to Ludlow Fair" 
        rel="http://www.link.com">
          blah</div>
```

I do not see any different between using a caption with or without spaces, but breaking your tag like that is non-standard, if not actually wrong ( and it doesn't seem to actually be wrong based on some very quick research). It does look like the kind of thing that Javascript could choke on though. I'd suggest rewriting that so that it generates a bit more typical markup.

```
function Shortcode_Caption( $atts, $content=null ){

   // DEFAULT ARGUMENTS ARRAY       
   $args=shortcode_atts( array(
    'caption' => 'Caption',
    'link' => 'http://www.link.com'
   ), $atts);

   // ENCLOSED SHORTCODES
   if($content){
      $ret = '<div class="Container-Caption"'; 
      $ret .= ' alt="'. $args['caption'] .'"';
      $ret .= ' rel="'. $args['link'] .'">';
      $ret .=  $content.'</div>';
      return $ret;
   };
};  

add_shortcode( 'mycaption', 'Shortcode_Caption' );

echo do_shortcode('[mycaption caption="Oh I have been to Ludlow Fair" ]blah[/mycaption]');
```

Also note that you are breaking a rule specifically spelled out in the Codex:

> ***Shortcode names should be all lowercase*** and use all letters, but
>   numbers and underscores should work fine too. Be wary of using hyphens
>   (dashes), you'll be better off not using them.
>
> http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API