# Input with spaces in Shortcode attributes overwritten by defaults

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, shortcode, customization

question seems to be similar to the one [asked here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/139089/space-in-wordpress-attribute-causing-problems) but the answer went down a different path.

Pretty much if a user enters a shortcode attribute with a space it will get overwritten by the default value and I can't figure out how to stop this behavior (no mention in the WP Shortcode API docs)

Shorcode:

```
[imageaccordion title="We're awesome"]Content Here[/imageaccordion]
```

PHP:

```
function image_accordion( $atts , $content = null ) {

    // Attributes

    extract(
        shortcode_atts(
            array(
                'title' => 'Accordion Title',
            ), $atts , 'imageaccordion'
        )
    );

    // Put It Together

    ob_start();
    ?>
    <div class='image-accordion'>
          <h2>
            <?php echo $title; ?>
          </h2>
    <?php

    $outputbefore = ob_get_clean();
    $outputafter = '</div>';

    //Return 

    return $outputbefore . do_shortcode($content) . $outputafter;
}

add_shortcode( 'imageaccordion', 'image_accordion' );
```

I seem to get an output of

```
<div class="image-accordion'>
  <h2>
     Accordion Title
  </h2>
</div>
```

Every time...

If I run a print_r on $atts I get

```
Array ( [0] => 
/> [2] => title="We're [3] => Awesome")
```

This is on a new installation of WP, no plugins running with the default theme

(have cut down the eg. code too)

Comment: There's nothing special that WP does with attributes containing spaces - just tried your shortcode and it works fine - can only think `$title` is getting overwritten in code between the extract and echo that isn't shown...

Comment: Hmm, i've posted the full code here: http://chopapp.com/#lg49uyj3

Nope, nothing that overwriting the variable...

Seems to happen on all vars with spaces too, can't figure it out

Comment: Again worked! However, if you're calling it like in the usage example with newlines between attributes then WP won't like that ... try one line `[imageaccordion title="We're Value" hovertext="Blah blah hover"]`

Comment: Yep, looks like the multiline was the problem...

Thanks for checking it out :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I was multi-lining the shortcode itself, wordpress wasn't a fan.

Thanks @bonger

Comment: Actually, looking at the `shortcode_parse_atts` code, it'd be an easy fix for WP to deal with this (which it should) by just stripping the `<br />`'s, eg `$text = preg_replace('/<br \/>$/m', '', $text);` - might open a ticket on this ... then again, probably won't :( ...

Comment: This is happening to me, yet I am definitely not multi-lining the code. Any other explanations?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in output buffering. Why not just use assignment operators?

```
function image_accordion( $atts , $content = null ) {

    // Attributes
    $args = shortcode_atts( array(
        'title' => 'Accordion Title',
    ), $atts , 'imageaccordion' );

    $output = '<div class="image-accordion">';
        $output .= '<h2>' . $args['title'] . '</h2>';
    $output .= '</div>';

    $output .= do_shortcode($content);

    return $output;
}
add_shortcode( 'imageaccordion', 'image_accordion' );
```